# How prevent STDOUT of Plugin_Upgrader->upgrade(...)?

Tags: plugins, php, rest-api, updates, upgrade

### ️ Code

```php
function my_custom_endpoint(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
  $plugin_file = $request->get_param("plugin_file");

  if(!class_exists('Plugin_Upgrader'))
  {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php';
  }

  ob_start();
  $upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader();
  $result = $upgrader->upgrade($plugin_file);
  $logs = ob_get_clean();

  // I m testing here if the upgrade is successfull before return the response

  return rest_ensure_response(array("logs" => $logs));
}
```

### ⛔ The issue

I create a custom WordPress REST endpoint to update some plugin from another website.

The method `Plugin_Upgrader::upgrade` write a lot of strings in STDOUT, I wanna catch in `$logs` but when I try *buffering* it with `ob_start` I still get it in my http response.

```html
<divclass="wrap">
<h1></h1>
<p>downloading_package</p>
<p>L’authenticitéde<spanclass="code">complianz-gdpr.6.5.4.zip</span>
n’apaspuêtrevérifiéecaraucunesignaturen’aététrouvée.</p>
<p>unpack_package</p>
<p>Installationdeladernièreversion&#8230;</p>
<p>remove_old</p>
<p>process_success</p>
</div>
<b>Warning</b>: Cannotmodifyheaderinformation-headersalreadysentby(outputstartedatC: \xampp\htdocs\oust\wp-includes\functions.php: 5349)in<b>C: \xampp\htdocs\oust\wp-includes\rest-api\class-wp-rest-server.php</b>online<b>1769</b><br/>
{
  'logs' => false
}
```

> *French Logs Sorry*

> [PHP ob_get_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php): If output buffering isn't active then false is returned.

This return seems to be the cause of all my problems, but I don't understand why buffering is deactivate after  `$upgrader->upgrade($plugin_file)` call (I tried replace it with simple echo and the buffering work)..

### ‍♂️ Expected

```json
{
  "logs": "<divclass="wrap"><h1></h1><p>downloading_package</p><p>L’authenticitéde<spanclass="code">complianz-gdpr.6.5.4.zip</span>n’apaspuêtrevérifiéecaraucunesignaturen’aététrouvée.</p><p>unpack_package</p><p>Installationdeladernièreversion&#8230;</p><p>remove_old</p><p>process_success</p></div>"
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions ❤️

Comment: can you expand your initial code block? It's unclear what comes _before_ the `ob_start` or when you're including the various files to get the plugin upgrader class. If there's nothing of note then it's best we can see that to avoid repeated unnecessary questions

Comment: Code block updated

Comment: thanks, I also noticed that you're not using the rest request object and bypassing it straight to `$_POST` like this: `$plugin_file = $_POST['plugin_file'];` is there a reason for this? Would it not be safer/more compatible to do this: `function my_custom_endpoint( \WP_REST_Request $request) : \WP_REST_Response|\WP_Error {` and `$plugin_file = $request['plugin_file'];`? The REST API will take care of figuring out if it's GET or POST, using `$_POST` directly means none of the validation or sanitisation features will work

Comment: also have you tried moving the `ob_start` to before the `if` statement that requires the file? I can't find anything in the WP source that messes or uses output buffers for upgrading, is it possible somewhere in your code a filter is flushing the output buffer?

Comment: (1) It's a POST function; I'm new to WordPress REST API, so there was no particular reason and I'll  refactoring it with WP_REST_Request implementation, thanks !

(2) Put ob_start before the file import didn't solve the problem and I'm not using any filter

Comment: double check as a plugin you didn't write or the theme may be using output buffers and closing it more times than it's opened, or trying to cache/optimise output

Comment: also, you could adjust the plugin upgrader class and replace its `skin` attribute with an upgrader skin of your own that has no output, the purpose of the upgrader skin is to do all the output and display, the upgrader class itself doesn't output anything, though that doesn't answer your output buffering question

Comment: (1) I'm doing my tests with a plugin that doesn't belong to me (https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/complianz-gdpr/ — version used 6.5.0). I do have buffer usages in my theme, but when the api is called, `[shortcodes]` isn't supposed to load, is it? I'll try with another plugin (2) Thanks a lot, I'll have a look at it and although it doesn't solve the initial problem it will allow me to work around it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ✨ Explanation and Solution

Updating the plugin to prevent standard output couldn't be easier. No need to create a custom skin, WordPress already provides one for this case:

[Automatic_Upgrader_Skin](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/automatic_upgrader_skin/)

> Description: This skin is designed to be used when no output is intended, all output is captured and stored for the caller to process and log/email/discard.

After digging a lot I found that after every plugin update the next action is called `'upgrader_process_complete', array('Language_Pack_Upgrader', 'async_upgrade')`. This action is called to update other parts such as the language packs.

This action create new instance of `Language_Pack_Upgrader` with a new custom `Language_Pack_Upgrader_Skin` which also generates data in the standard output.

But if the `WP_Upgrader` who call it use and `Automatic_Upgrader_Skin` the `Language_Pack_Upgrader` will reuse it.

We therefore only need the following few lines to prevent standard output during an update:

```php
$skin = new Automatic_Upgrader_Skin();
$plugin_upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader($skin);
$result = $plugin_upgrader->upgrade($name);
```

### Why `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` doesn't work

Skins generated by the "upgrader_process_complete" action call the `skin->feekback()` method, which in turn calls [show_message()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/show_message/).

This contains the following lines, which broke my first implementation.

```php
wp_ob_end_flush_all();
flush();
```